# How output defined in java map put?

Tags: java

Please let me know how output of below java code is defined

```
Map m=new HashMap();
m.put("A", "B");
m.put("A", m.put("A", "C"));
```

output:
**A,B**

till 2nd line it is A,B
after going in m.put("A","C") it is becoming A,C
last m.put("A", m.put("A", "C")); is taking key as "A" and value as "B"
please let me know how it works?

Comment: Have you read the documentation to see what the return value of `put` is?

Comment: By the way, you're using *raw types* (`Map` and `HashMap`). **Never use raw types.** Always provide the necessary type arguments. In your case, `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for the put](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) method you'll notice that it returns

> the previous value associated with key

So in this case `m.put("A", "C")` is returning `"B"` (because that's what we `put` in the map with the previous statement) and storing `"C"`, which gets immediately discarded by `m.put("A", m.put("A", "C"));` which is at that point equivalent to `m.put("A", "B");`

Comment: Thanks got it ,
was confused on return type V put(K key, V value);
was thinking it is returning null or the current V value